# How to format strings with tuples of values like using %(name)s

Tags: python, string, formatting, string-formatting, text-formatting

I've always seen formatting strings by placing tuples of values in between the modulo symbol and `s` character like using `%(levelno)s:%(message)s` from the Python logging module in a string for the `fmt` parameter argument for a `Formatter` instance would return the message and level number in the format string, and I have always wondered how it has created that format system. How do I make a formatting system like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is formatting strings by using the modulo operator (`%s`) as well as mapping format values using a `dict`, like this:
`print('Hello, %(name)s!' % {'name': 'Jack'})`

Comment: @MarcoEl-Korashy Yep, that's that what I was looking for. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a tuple to a print call and use `%s` for strings, `%d` for decimal numbers, and `%f` for floats, among a whole host of other things.

`%` is used as the String Formatting Operator, rather than modulo.

```
>>> print("We can represent %s with a rounded %f" % ("pi", 3.14))
"We can represent the number pi with a rounded 3.14"
```

Docs here: [% (String Formatting Operator)](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/formatting.html)

Comment: Thanks, @chemicalwill , but that's not what I was looking for.